# What do I need to change to upload two of the same applications to a Windows tablet thus haveing two seperate applications

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am new to visual studios Windows development and I have made an application for a Windows tablet on 8.1. I want to copy the app then change some of the colors on the application and then make it a separate app from its copy. The problem is because the only difference in the applications is some code for the color, if one of the applications is already uploaded to my tablet, when I side load the other it just replaces the previous application. So what would I need to change in my one of my applications so my tablet would recognize them as two different apps.

Answer (score 0):

Each app must have a unique `Identity` set in the the App's manifest. See [Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/apps/br211441) and [other info about deploying Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/apps/hh464929) on MSDN.